# Determining slope percentage using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem, slope

I am working on a project where I need to conduct a MCA. One of the criteria is: if the slopes are greater than 15%, they should not be used at all. I have DEM model and a slope has been made in Degree.

How can I determine the 15% from the slope if it is in Degree?

Answer (score 2):

Slope angle is equal to `Atan(slope ratio)*180/Pi`

For a slope ratio of 15/100, the angle in degrees is `8.53`

You don't need to convert all the slopes values from your raster in degrees, just use this 8.53 threshold to apply a 'greater than' or 'smaller than test (assuming you just need the slope values for this threshold test)